# Pytest - Error No Module Named Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pytest

I tried to import sqlalchemy to my pytest file but when I tried to run it shows this error, even though I have already installed sqlalchemy.

```
    new.py:1: in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
E   ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

my code :

```
import pytest
import sqlalchemy
```

the code was just when I was importing the sqlalchemy.
How do I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have only python 2 in your system or both 2 and 3?

Comment: @SaraSantana only python 2.6 and 2.7, I run this code using py.test

Comment: @SaraSantana I figure out installed the sqlalchemy on python2.7. any idea how to run this?

Comment: run "pip list" in command line. do you see sqlalchemy?

Comment: @SaraSantana yes, I saw it

Comment: now in command line type: "python -V" notice that V is capital. what do you see and in what version of python you import sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, and fixed by running tests with:

```
python -m pytest .
```